# Install the OSGi Bundle using the ByteArray

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to install an OSGi bundle in OSGi container. I have a jar file in one of my folder.. I read that jar file into `ByteArray` and then I am using this `ByteArray` to install the `Framework` bundle in OSGi container. Below is the code..

```
FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();

framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(new HashMap<String, String>());
framework.start();

final String basePath = "C:\\LocalStorage";
final BundleContext bundleContext = framework.getBundleContext();
final List<Bundle> installedBundles = new LinkedList<Bundle>();

String filename = "Framework" + "-" + "1.0.0" + ".jar";
String localFilename = basePath+ File.separatorChar + filename;

File file = new File(localFilename);
byte [] fileData = new byte[(int)file.length()];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream((new FileInputStream(file)));
dis.readFully(fileData);
dis.close();

// But below line gives me exception always-
installedBundles.add(bundleContext.installBundle(filename, new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData)));

for (Bundle bundle : installedBundles) {
    bundle.start();
}
```

Below is the exception, I always get-

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: Framework:1.0.0
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing? And I need to use ByteArray because, in some of my code in another class, I am using ByteArray, so I need to pass the ByteArray of the jars file to those method..

**Update:-**

But if I am installing it like this, then it works fine. It doesn't works if I am installing it through ByteArray..

```
final String basePath = "C:\\LocalStorage";
final BundleContext bundleContext = framework.getBundleContext();
final List<Bundle> installedBundles = new LinkedList<Bundle>();

String filename = "Framework" + "-" + "1.0.0" + ".jar";
String localFilename = Constants.FILE_PROTOCOL + basePath+ File.separatorChar + filename;

installedBundles.add(bundleContext.installBundle(localFilename));

for (Bundle bundle : installedBundles) {
    bundle.start();
}
```

It might be possible that I am doing something wrong with ByteArray thing? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you already have a bundle with the same Symbolic Name and Version. These two together are like the "primary key" of each bundle; you can have two versions of the same bundle present, but you cannot have two bundles with the same name *and* version.

I still don't understand why you need to pass the byte array... why not pass the FileInputStream, since you already have that?

Anyway, I'll leave it for you to work out why you're loading the same bundle twice. NB the filename is NOT significant, only the `Bundle-SymbolicName` and `Bundle-Version` entries in the MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: Thanks Neil, then my question will be, why it does work with my second approach as stated in my question? `BundleContext.installBundle(String location)`. Everything is same, only the approach is different.

Comment: It's impossible to say... your code sample only shows the installation of one bundle, not the second. The error can only happen the second time you try to install the same bundle. Try using a debugger.

Comment: You probably have run the code more than once and you do not initialize your framework. Once a bundle is installed you have to update it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're lacking some OSGi headers in the MANIFEST.MF of the jar you're installing. Try adding some meta-data entries like these:

`Bundle-SymbolicName: your.name.Class`

`Bundle-Version: 1.0.0`

Check out the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)

Comment: I already have these entries in my `MANIFEST.MF file` - `Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Framework
Bundle-SymbolicName: Framework
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You tried to install OSGi framework bundle manually additionally to Framework system bundle already initialized by FrameworkFactory (this is the same bundle/file). This is the cause of your exception (read details [here](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleException.html#DUPLICATE_BUNDLE_ERROR)).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, Framework is not the real name for that.. It was a very long name so I need to shorten it before posting it here.